# Issue using gcloud scp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to transfer a file from a Google Compute Engine VM instance to my local machine using `gcloud scp`. I am able to confirm that I am logged in to the Google Cloud account using:

```
gcloud config list
```

However when I execute the `gcloud scp` command, I see following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) You do not currently have an active account selected.
```

Not sure why I am seeing the error even if I am logged in.

Here is how I am executing the command:

`gcloud scp <instance_name>: <remote_file_path> .`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This link [activate service account](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) may help you..

Comment: Perform a `gcloud auth login`. No service account required.

Comment: I did perform 'gcloud auth login;. Was able to login successfully. But still seeing that error

Comment: Could you please update your post sharing how you are executing your [scp command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp)?

Comment: For the error message, did you [initialize](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/initializing) gcloud CLI? Another reference [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing).

Comment: Try to run the command with `--verbosity=debug` & `--log-http` and please update your post with the output. These flags display more information about the state of the request sent with the gcloud commands.